# How to query GitHub api for "require approvals" number?

Tags: github, github-api

I need to find out which repos have the "require approvals" settings at <2. We have hundreds, so need an automated way to search this.

Never used GithUb Api before, but I looked and there's a query to retrieve a repo object. However, I don't see that number.

Is it possible to get this information? If so, what's the api call to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not seeing this setting in the repository object is that it's not a repository-level setting.  It's a setting that applies to the requirement to use pull requests for merging into certain branches, which is controlled by branch protection for the target branches.

The REST API does have [an endpoint from which you can fetch this information](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/branches#get-pull-request-review-protection), however.